# Extract nested dictionary values in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator, nested

I think I'm close but spinning in circles on this one. I have a dictionary in Python that has been imported from JSON. The raw data is too much to post here. The code works like I want and prints what I want, except it only returns the last value from the dictionary. How would I modify this to return all values and print exactly how it is shown here? Ultimately I want to take this data and add it to a database as one entry.

Code:

```
text = json.loads(content)

a = {}

def extract(DictIn, Dictout):
    for key, value in DictIn.iteritems():
        if isinstance(value, dict): 
            extract(value, Dictout)
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            for i in value:
                extract(i, Dictout)
        else:
            Dictout[key] = value

extract(text, a)

for k, v in a.iteritems():
    print k, ":", v
```

Result should look like the following, but have the other 40 or so entries. Currently the code only shows the last entry:

```
datetime : 2014-06-10T20:00:00-0600
date : 2014-06-10
href : http://xxxxxxxxxxxx.json
lng : -94.5554
id : 17551289
createdAt : 2013-07-30T12:18:56+0100
city : Kansas City, MO, US
billing : headline
totalEntries : 37
type : Concert
billingIndex : 1
status : ok
perPage : 50
setlistsHref : xxxxxxxxxxxx:51b7f46f-6c0f-46f2-9496-08c9ec2624d4/setlists.json
lat : 39.0763
displayName : Ben Folds
eventsHref : http://xxxxxxx.08c9ec2624d4/calendar.json
popularity : 0.0
uri : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
mbid : xxxxxxxxxxx
onTourUntil : 2014-06-10
time : 20:00:00
page : 1
```

Comment: What happens if there's an array in an array in the JSON? Or if the top level is an array?

Comment: I would suggest to look at the json itself, there is every chance that you are overwriting keys in the DictOut. This is because the 'leaves' of the dict/list json tree have the same key names, so when you 'flatten' that leaf, you are overwriting the previously flattened leaf that had the same keys. And so, you only seem to get one entry because you've overwritten all the others.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `Dictout[key] = value`

in Python Dictionary the `keys` are `unique`

Assume

```
_d = {1: 'one', 2: 'two'}

>>> print _d
{1: 'one', 2: 'two'}

>>> _d[1] = 'another one'
>>> print _d
{1: 'another one', 2: 'two'}
```

I guess in your for loop you are `overwriting value` of an existing `key`, that's why only your last entry is getting stored !.

Try changing your data structure, something like `list of dictionaries`, so that your output may look like,

```
my_out_list = [{1: 'one', 2: 'two'}, {1: 'another one', 2: 'two'}]
```